# Purchasing a replacement Tallis

Tags: product-recommendation, tallit-gadol, size

I am replacing a custom made tallis. What should I look for? What are the dimensions that I need? I do not wear mine covering my head.

Comment: The best way to decide is to just try it on?!

Comment: Dov, that only works in an area where you have stores you can go into.  For many of us who live in areas with smaller Jewish communities, we have to use on line shopping.  Many web sites have guides for sizing based on your height.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/530120/jewish/Purchasing-a-Kosher-Tallit.htm

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Elijah and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try [Ben's Tallit Shop](https://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/tallit-sizes/) which has a "Tallit Size Wizard" which takes you through the steps of picking the right sizing.

Answer (score -1):

Do u know the pic of the Renaissance man? Well, if I stand the way he does my Tallit is as tall as I am and as wide as my out stretched arms. I like it covering my entire head and it also covers my face. People cant see my face cause it is buried in the Tallith. When I stand, the tzitzith are maybe 6 inches off the ground.